# What constitutes a nonzero value in tsql?

Tags: sql, t-sql

In t-sql, when you convert anything to datatype bit any nonzero value is converted to true. I am working on the premise of the column not being nullable. I would consider NULL to be a nonzero value, and surely if you convert the value null into datatype bit you would expect it to be 0 (AKA false).

This being said I wonder what exactly constitutes a nonzero value, as based on null being (as I consider it) a nonzero value it would be converted to the value 1 (true).

So my question really becomes is NULL a nonzero value, or is the value NULL (being the lack of a value) actually completely separate and does not count as a nonzero value or zero, and counts simply as NULL itself - and if this is the case then what would it be converted to if inserted into a non nullable column?

Many Thanks,

Comment: `NULL` is indeterminant. It's as much `Non-Zero` as it is `Non-One`. The answer to the question `Is NULL non-zero?` is `NULL`. And `NULL` isn't `TRUE`.  And only `TRUE` allows a boolean test to succeed.

Comment: By the way this is a somewhat hypothetical question as I'm fully aware that inserting NULL into a non-nullable column will just make the insert fail! I see, so NULL itself is separate to both non-zero and non-one - Thanks Dems.

Answer (score 0):

In TSQL, NULL is considered an unknown value which is why `NULL <> 0 = NULL` and not 1 when converting to bit.

Comment: I understand that, but in theory if inserting NULL into a non nullable bit column didn't make the insert fail then what would the value actually become?

Comment: NULL is unknown and cannot 'become' anything else.

Comment: Not sure how anyone could answer "If it were to not fail, then what would it do?"

Comment: @AakashM - exactly, which is why I didn't answer it :)  But... "if it were to not fail", then either a bug exists in TSQL or it would be converted to something else and Microsoft would have documented the feature.  Since there isn't any documentation on this automatic conversion feature, and it does in fact fail (no bug), I see no point in discussing it.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was @user1323780 :)

Comment: @Chris Gessler. As I said in a previous comment this is a hypothetical question - I know it has no relevance in practice. As regards the conversion I apologize for my wording, I meant if you were to manually convert it.

Comment: @user1323780 - I suppose in that case it would depend on your business logic.  Personally, I would use default (0|1) depending upon your need.  But... if you convert NULL to BIT, it will just be NULL unless you use the IsNull() method and specify a default value.

Comment: @ChrisGessler - thanks for the clarification, I was just intrigued - it was more to expand my theoretical knowledge than practical :)